# In R shiny, how to trigger change in main panel table rendering after clicking an action button?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

In the below MWE code, when running, if the user is (1) currently viewing the rates values table in the main panel (after having clicked on "Rates values" action button on top of main panel), then (2) clicks on the "Modify Liabilities Structure" action button in the sidebar panel and makes a change to the liabilities structure input grid in the ensuing modal dialogue box, and then (3) dismisses the modal dialogue, then (4) the user remains in the Rates values table in the main panel.

Similarly, if the user is (1) currently viewing the liabilities structure table in the main panel, then (2) clicks on the "Modify Rates and Coupons" action button in the sidebar panel and makes a change to row A of the matrix input grid (the only operative row) in the ensuing modal dialogue, and then (3) dismisses the modal dialogue, then (4) the user remains in the liabilities structure table in the main panel.

I'd like any change to the input grid after clicking "Modify Liabilities Structure" to cause the liabilities table ("`table3`") to be rendered in the main panel, regardless of what was previously in the main panel. Similarly, I'd like any change to the input grid after clicking "Modify Rates and Coupons" to cause the rates table ("`table4`") to be rendered in the main panel, regardless of what was previously in the main panel.

Essentially, I need to trigger some sort of "Go to" function for main panel table rendering after making a change to an input grid in a modal dialogue box. I don't know how to do this. In the below MWE, my unsuccessful attempts at doing this sort of "Go to" are marked "`# ATTEMPT` >"

MWE code:

```
library(shiny);library(shinyMatrix);library(shinyjs)

colnames(matrix3Default) <- paste0("Series ",1:ncol(matrix3Default))

matrix3Default <- matrix(c(1,24,0,100),4,1,dimnames=list(matrix3Headers(), NULL))

matrix3Headers <- function(){c('A','B','C','D')}

matrix3Input <- function(x, matrix3Default){
  matrixInput(x,label =  'Input series terms into below grid:',
              value =  matrix3Default, 
              rows  =  list(extend=FALSE,names=TRUE), 
              cols  =  list(extend=TRUE,names=TRUE,editableNames=FALSE,delete=TRUE),
              class =  'numeric')}

matrix4Default <- matrix(c(0.2), 4, 1,dimnames=list(c("A","B","C","D"),NULL))

matrix4Input <- function(x,matrix4Input){
  matrixInput(x,value = matrix4Input,
              rows = list(extend=FALSE,names=TRUE),
              cols = list(extend=FALSE,names=FALSE,editableNames=FALSE),
              class = "numeric")}

vectorBaseRate <- function(x,y){
  a <- rep(y,x)
  b <- seq(1:x)
  c <- data.frame(x = b, y = a)
  return(c)}

vectorBaseRatePlot <- function(w,x,y,z){plot(w[,1],sapply(w[,2], function(x)gsub("%","",x)),
                                             main=x,xlab=y,ylab=z,type="b")}

ui <- 
  pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("Model..."),
    sidebarPanel(fluidRow(helpText(h5(strong("Base Input Panel")),align="center")),uiOutput("Panels")),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Liabilities module", value=4,
                 fluidRow(h5(strong(helpText("Select model output to view:")))),
                 fluidRow(
                   actionButton('showLiabStructBtn','Liabilities'),
                   actionButton('showRatesValueBtn','Rates values'),
                   actionButton('showRatesPlotBtn','Rates plots')), 
                 uiOutput('showResults')), 
        id = "tabselected"))) 

server <- function(input,output,session)({
  
  showResults <- reactiveValues()
  rv          <- reactiveValues( # Used for matrix 3 (liability structure) inputs
    mat3       = matrix3Input('matrix3',matrix3Default),
    input      = matrix3Default,
    colHeader  = colnames(input))
  matrix4     <- reactive(input$matrix4)
  baseRate    <- function(){vectorBaseRate(60,input$matrix4[1,1])} 
  
  output$Panels <- renderUI({
    tagList( 
      conditionalPanel(condition="input.tabselected==4",
                       actionButton('modLiabStruct','Modify Liabilities Structure'),
                       actionButton('modRates','Modify Rates and Coupons'))
    ) # close tagList
  }) # close renderUI
  
  vectorLiabStruct <- reactive({
    if(!isTruthy(input$modLiabStruct)){ # << Generates default table when first invoking the App
      df <- matrix3Default
      n <- dim(df)[2]
      colnames(df) <- paste("Series", 1:n)
      rownames(df) <- matrix3Headers()
    }
    else{ # 
      req(input$matrix3) 
      rv$mat3 <- matrix3Input('matrix3',input$matrix3) 
      df <- input$matrix3
      n <- dim(df)[2]
      colnames(df) <- paste("Series", 1:n)
      rownames(df) <- matrix3Headers()
      rv$input <- df
    } # close else
    df
  })
  
  output$table3 <- renderTable({
    if(!isTruthy(input$modLiabStruct)){
      df <- matrix3Default
      n <- dim(df)[2]
      colnames(df) <- paste("Series", 1:n)
      rownames(df) <- matrix3Headers()
    }
    else{  
      req(input$matrix3) 
      rv$mat3 <- matrix3Input('matrix3',input$matrix3)
      df <- input$matrix3
      n <- dim(df)[2]
      colnames(df) <- paste("Series", 1:n)
      rownames(df) <- matrix3Headers()
      rv$input <- df
    } # close else
    df
  },rownames=TRUE, colnames=TRUE) # close output$table3
  
  vectorRates <- reactive({
    if (is.null(input$modRates)){df <- NULL}
    else {if(input$modRates < 1){df <- cbind(Period = 1:60,BaseRate = 0.2)}
      else {
        req(input$matrix4)
        df <- cbind(Period = 1:60,BaseRate = baseRate()[,2])
      } # close 2nd else
    } # close 1st else
    df
  }) # close reactive
  
  output$table4 <- renderTable({vectorRates()})
  
  observeEvent(input$modLiabStruct,{
    showModal(modalDialog( 
      rv$mat3,
      footer = tagList(
        actionButton("resetLiabStruct","Reset"),
        modalButton("Close")
      ), # close tag list
    ))} # close show modal and modal dialog
    # ATTEMPT >  {showResults$showme <- tagList(tableOutput("table3"))}
  ) # close observe event
  
  observeEvent(input$showLiabStructBtn,
               {showResults$showme <- tagList(tableOutput("table3"))},ignoreNULL = FALSE)  
  
  observeEvent(input$resetLiabStruct, {updateMatrixInput(session,'matrix3', matrix3Default)})
  observeEvent(input$resetRatesStruct, {updateMatrixInput(session,'matrix4', matrix4Default)})
  
  observeEvent(input$showRatesValueBtn,
               {showResults$showme <- tagList(tableOutput("table4"))},ignoreNULL = TRUE)
  
  output$graph1 <-renderPlot(vectorBaseRatePlot(vectorRates(),"A Variable","Period","Rate"))
  observeEvent(input$showRatesPlotBtn,{showResults$showme <- plotOutput("graph1")})
  
  output$showResults <- renderUI({showResults$showme})
  
  observeEvent(input$modRates,
               {showModal(modalDialog(
                 matrix4Input("matrix4",if(is.null(input$matrix4)) matrix4Default else input$matrix4),
                 useShinyjs(),
                 footer = tagList(
                   actionButton("resetRatesStruct","Reset"), 
                   modalButton("Close")
                 )))} # close taglist, modalDialog, showModal, and showModal function
               # ATTEMPT > {showResults$showme <- tagList(tableOutput("table4"))}
  ) # close observeEvent
  
}) # close server

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were having a good attempt.
Just move your 'goto' inside the curly braces:

```
{showModal(modalDialog(
      matrix4Input("matrix4",if(is.null(input$matrix4)) matrix4Default else input$matrix4),
      useShinyjs(),
      footer = tagList(
        actionButton("resetRatesStruct","Reset"), 
        modalButton("Close")
      )))
      showResults$showme <- tagList(tableOutput("table4")) ### this line 
    } ## above this curly brace
```

Comment: An added benefit of this "go to" is that the underlying table that is being modified appears in the background, beneath the modal dialogue, so you can see your changes reflected in main panel table in real-time. A

Comment: Yes, I really liked that effect. Reactive values used this way give us much more control that output$items alone; for example, you can have, say ,  right sidebar content based on a 'switch' of a reactive value, and change that depending on where the user is navigating in the app. great ui effect!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking for this.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)
library(shinyjs)

matrix3Headers <- function(){c('A','B','C','D')}

matrix3Default <- matrix(c(1,24,0,100),4,1,dimnames=list(matrix3Headers(), NULL))
colnames(matrix3Default) <- paste0("Series ",1:ncol(matrix3Default))


matrix3Input <- function(x, matrix3Default){
  matrixInput(x,label =  'Input series terms into below grid:',
              value =  matrix3Default, 
              rows  =  list(extend=FALSE,names=TRUE), 
              cols  =  list(extend=TRUE,names=TRUE,editableNames=FALSE,delete=TRUE),
              class =  'numeric')}

matrix4Default <- matrix(c(0.2), 4, 1,dimnames=list(c("A","B","C","D"),NULL))

matrix4Input <- function(x,matrix4Input){
  matrixInput(x,value = matrix4Input,
              rows = list(extend=FALSE,names=TRUE),
              cols = list(extend=FALSE,names=FALSE,editableNames=FALSE),
              class = "numeric")}

vectorBaseRate <- function(x,y){
  a <- rep(y,x)
  b <- seq(1:x)
  c <- data.frame(x = b, y = a)
  return(c)}

vectorBaseRatePlot <- function(w,x,y,z){plot(w[,1],sapply(w[,2], function(x)gsub("%","",x)),
                                             main=x,xlab=y,ylab=z,type="b")}

ui <- 
  pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("Model..."),
    sidebarPanel(fluidRow(helpText(h5(strong("Base Input Panel")),align="center")),uiOutput("Panels")),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Liabilities module", value=4,
                 fluidRow(h5(strong(helpText("Select model output to view:")))),
                 fluidRow(
                   actionButton('showLiabStructBtn','Liabilities'),
                   actionButton('showRatesValueBtn','Rates values'),
                   actionButton('showRatesPlotBtn','Rates plots')), 
                 uiOutput('showResults')), 
        id = "tabselected"))) 

server <- function(input,output,session)({
  
  showResults <- reactiveValues()
  rv          <- reactiveValues( # Used for matrix 3 (liability structure) inputs
    mat3       = matrix3Input('matrix3',matrix3Default),
    input      = matrix3Default,
    colHeader  = colnames(input))
  matrix4     <- reactive(input$matrix4)
  baseRate    <- function(){vectorBaseRate(60,input$matrix4[1,1])} 
  
  output$Panels <- renderUI({
    tagList( 
      conditionalPanel(condition="input.tabselected==4",
                       actionButton('modLiabStruct','Modify Liabilities Structure'),
                       actionButton('modRates','Modify Rates and Coupons'))
    ) # close tagList
  }) # close renderUI
  
  vectorLiabStruct <- reactive({
    if(!isTruthy(input$modLiabStruct)){ # << Generates default table when first invoking the App
      df <- matrix3Default
      n <- dim(df)[2]
      colnames(df) <- paste("Series", 1:n)
      rownames(df) <- matrix3Headers()
    }
    else{ # 
      req(input$matrix3) 
      rv$mat3 <- matrix3Input('matrix3',input$matrix3) 
      df <- input$matrix3
      n <- dim(df)[2]
      colnames(df) <- paste("Series", 1:n)
      rownames(df) <- matrix3Headers()
      rv$input <- df
    } # close else
    df
  })
  
  output$table3 <- renderTable({
    if(!isTruthy(input$modLiabStruct)){
      df <- matrix3Default
      n <- dim(df)[2]
      colnames(df) <- paste("Series", 1:n)
      rownames(df) <- matrix3Headers()
    }
    else{  
      req(input$matrix3) 
      rv$mat3 <- matrix3Input('matrix3',input$matrix3)
      df <- input$matrix3
      n <- dim(df)[2]
      colnames(df) <- paste("Series", 1:n)
      rownames(df) <- matrix3Headers()
      rv$input <- df
    } # close else
    df
  },rownames=TRUE, colnames=TRUE) # close output$table3
  
  vectorRates <- reactive({
    if (is.null(input$modRates)){df <- NULL}
    else {if(input$modRates < 1){df <- cbind(Period = 1:60,BaseRate = 0.2)}
      else {
        req(input$matrix4)
        df <- cbind(Period = 1:60,BaseRate = baseRate()[,2])
      } # close 2nd else
    } # close 1st else
    df
  }) # close reactive
  
  output$table4 <- renderTable({vectorRates()})
  
  observeEvent(input$modLiabStruct,{
    showModal(modalDialog( 
      rv$mat3,
      footer = tagList(
        actionButton("resetLiabStruct","Reset"),
        #modalButton("Close")
        actionButton("close1","Close")
      ), # close tag list
    ))} # close show modal and modal dialog
    # ATTEMPT >  {showResults$showme <- tagList(tableOutput("table3"))}
  ) # close observe event
  
  observeEvent(input$close1,{
    removeModal()
    showResults$showme <- tagList(tableOutput("table3"))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$showLiabStructBtn,
               {showResults$showme <- tagList(tableOutput("table3"))},ignoreNULL = FALSE)  
  
  observeEvent(input$resetLiabStruct, {updateMatrixInput(session,'matrix3', matrix3Default)})
  observeEvent(input$resetRatesStruct, {updateMatrixInput(session,'matrix4', matrix4Default)})
  
  observeEvent(input$showRatesValueBtn,
               {showResults$showme <- tagList(tableOutput("table4"))},ignoreNULL = TRUE)
  
  output$graph1 <-renderPlot(vectorBaseRatePlot(vectorRates(),"A Variable","Period","Rate"))
  observeEvent(input$showRatesPlotBtn,{showResults$showme <- plotOutput("graph1")})
  
  output$showResults <- renderUI({showResults$showme})
  
  observeEvent(input$modRates,
               {showModal(modalDialog(
                 matrix4Input("matrix4",if(is.null(input$matrix4)) matrix4Default else input$matrix4),
                 useShinyjs(),
                 footer = tagList(
                   actionButton("resetRatesStruct","Reset"), 
                   #modalButton("Close")
                   actionButton("close2","Close")
                 )))} # close taglist, modalDialog, showModal, and showModal function
               # ATTEMPT > {showResults$showme <- tagList(tableOutput("table4"))}
  ) # close observeEvent
  
  observeEvent(input$close2,{
    removeModal()
    showResults$showme <- tagList(tableOutput("table4"))
  })
  
}) # close server

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Yes, exactly what I was looking for. Again I am saved by YBS! What you have done here is clear, thank you for being explicit with the changes. That way I can understand what's happening and learn something important.